# Console.log not printing in Sublime Text 3 (with Node Build System)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

I am using a Mac (Yosemite 10.10.3) and have installed the latest version of Node.js. I also tried creating new Build Systems for Node using every possible variant out there (they either produce error messages or the non-response below).

When I'm in JavaScript mode and try to run something as simple as:

```
console.log("hello");
```

in the bottom section when I hit command-B, all I get is:

[Finished in 0.1s]

No error message. But no printing to the console, either.

Naturally this makes Sublime almost useless since I can't test code in it. Any ideas on how I can fix this???

Comment: Does 'view -> Show console' give you any hints?

Comment: What's in your [build system configuration](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/basics.html)?

Comment: Are you running this file using node filename.js or some other way ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if .js files must be saved in order for builds to work. I saved the file and it prints to the console fine.